# Как уничтожить объект правильно в Java?

Tags: java

У меня есть собственная мапа

```
public class MyMap implements <String,String>{
...
}
```

Она что-то делает в БД, а в конце нужно сделать 2 destroy метода:

1. Если объект был уничтожен сборщиком мусора **без** вызова метода `close()`, то вызывался бы метод `clear()`
2. Если объект был уничтожен сборщиком **после** вызова `close()`, то все данные сохраняются в БД.

То есть сделать аналог закрытия потока в FileWriter. Закрыл - сохранил, не закрыл - потерял.

Нужно ли использовать `finalize()` или просто добавить `AutoCloseable` ?

Comment: Нельзя использовать `finalize`. На его вызов нельзя рассчитывать, он может приводить к трудноуловимым ошибкам и он сильно снижает работоспособность сборщика мусора. Именно поэтому он deprecated с 9-й версии Java. Просто проектируйте код правильно, чтобы сборка без вызова `close` была невозможна.

Answer (score 0):

Не используйте finalize(), потому что это устаревшая технология. 
Реализуйте AutoCloseable, а в целевом коде используйте класс только вместе с try-with-resources или внимательно проследите, чтобы был вызван метод close.

```
public class MyMap implements Map<String, String>, AutoCloseable {
  ...

  void close() {
    ...
  }
}
...
try(var map = new MyMap()) {
  ...
}
```